# need to set target method twice in viewcontroller and navigationcontroller - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer, navigationcontroller

There's a `NavigationController` which has a `ViewController` as a `rootViewController`

In this `ViewController` I declare a `panGestureRecogniser` like this:

```
guard let thisNavigationController = navigationController as? ProfileNavigationController else { return }

let panDown = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: thisNavigationController, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        panDown!.delegate = self
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panDown!)
```

As you can see I set the `target` of this gesture to be the `navigationController` of the `viewController` that I have previously carefully downcasted to its type.

The method `handleGesture` has been correctly declared and set to public in its own NavigationController class, in fact in `ProfileNavigationController` class I have set and declared public:

```
@objc public func handleGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
```

However I have this error `Cannot find 'handleGesture' in scope` in `ViewController` as if I should declare this method in `viewController` too even if the target is set to the `navigationController`.

If I don't set the method **also** in the `ViewController` (even if it's empty)  the code won't run and I don't know why is that.

If I set it empty in the `viewController` everything works fine. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use selector of `ProfileNavigationController` like:

```
let panDown = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: thisNavigationController, action: #selector(ProfileNavigationController.handleGesture))
```